# How can I add two pandas.DataFrames cellwise?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, cell

I have a bunch of `pandas.DataFrame`s which are each a table of **counts**. I'd like to sum them up to return the totals. I.e. cellwise, as if I was summing two dimensional histograms or two dimensional arrays. The output should be a table of the same dimensions as input, but with numerical values summed up.

To make matters worse, the order of the columns may not be preserved.

There must be a cool way to do this without looping, but I can't figure it out.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [3, 1, 2], 'B': [1, 1, 0]})
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'B': [2, 0, 1], 'A': [4, 1, 6]})
```

I'm looking for a function something like:

```
df_cellwise_sum = cellwise_sum(df1, df2)
print(df_cellwise_sum)
```

which makes:

```
   A  B
0  7  3
1  2  1
2  8  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html):

```
df = df1.add(df2)
```